# Agregar un nuevo TextBox en CyrstalReport mediante codigo

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

Buenos dias, estoy tratando de insertar un nuevo objeto de texto a un reporte crystal fuera de la aplicacion, he contruido un sistema en WPF en donde tengo un textbox en el cual deseo escribir lo que quiero insertar en el reporte y tambien hay un reportViewer donde se visualiza el reporte, alguien lo a hecho o se le ocurre como poder insertar un nuevo texto a crystalreport?

desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Rodolfo, bienvenido a [es.so]. No me queda claro __cuál es el problema exacto__ que estás enfrentando con tu implementación. Por favor revisa esta guía _[mcve]_. También te recomiendo que evites, en la medida de lo posible, solicitar ideas, sugerencias, opiniones o recomendaciones, ya que esas preguntas no se permiten en la comunidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad soy nuevo por aca y no sabia las reglas, lo siento, formulare mejor la problematica y lo volvere a publicar

Comment: Gracias. Y nuevamente, bienvenido.